# $http.post not acting as expected in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http-post

I've seen this topic discussed several times, but I'm still confused after reading every answer I've seen on this topic.

As many have before me, I'm trying to create this basic To Do app with CRUD features. I have the following (abridged to show relevant parts) code:

HTML:

```
        <div ng-repeat="item in items | orderObjectBy:sortby" ng-if="complete == 'N'">
            <strong>{{item.title}}</strong><br/>
            <em>{{item.details}}</em><br/>
            {{item.due}}<br/>
            <form>Mark Complete? <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.complete" value="Y"></form>
            <a href="#/item/edit/{{item.id}}">Edit this item</a>
            <br/>
            <hr/>           
        </div>

    <button ng-click="save()">Save changes</button>
```

JS in controller:

```
    $scope.save = function() {
    $http.post('js/services/items.json', $scope.items).success(function(data) {
        $scope.msg = 'Data saved' + JSON.stringify($scope.items);
    });
};
```

When I check a "Completed" box, and then "Save Changes", I get the data dump of the updated JSON but it never actually updated the JSON file on the server. That path is the same exact path I use to get the JSON in the first place. There are no errors thrown. It simply doesn't do it.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Err, I'm confused...you expect that posting your json data to the server will update your file?  Based on what premise?

Comment: Shortcut method to perform POST request is post(url, data). Do you specify correct URL to your service? Does this service URL expect to receive POST requests?

Comment: I guess this is what I'm missing. Based on what I read, I thought that I can use $http.post and it will update the JSON file on the server. I'm asking now what was the step that I'm clearly missing to make that actually work?

Answer (score 1):

javascript is a client side language and doesn't have access to the server's file system, so angular itself can not update that file on the web server.

to do server side file manipulation, you need to use a server side language such as php or .net

Comment: Ok. I'm working with Php, so you're saying I need to actually submit the form and let the Php manipulate the file? So, what exactly does $http.post() do?

Comment: that command makes a request to your web server. it is up to php to manipulate the files on the server and serve up a response to the request accordingly

Comment: But, if I'm already going back to the server with a form submission, why would I need the http.post? Or, are you saying that the URL in the http.post should be the Php file that will manipulate the JSON? But that doesn't make sense since how would that Php file have the updated information? It doesn't seem to me that it would be able to read that second param of the content.

Comment: Ok, now I'm a little more confused as well. What inspired this ToDo app is a request I got from a company. Based on what's being said here, it seems to have two conflicting requirements: 1) User can reload page and see updates 2) This should not require a server component. :( They want this done 100% on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Angular service to call service side

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('service', service);

    function service($http) {
        var url = 'api/todo';

        var service = {
            update: update
        };

        return service;

        function update(id, data, callback, errorCallback) {
            if (id) {
                $http({
                    method: 'PUT',
                    url: url + '/' + id,
                    data: data
                })
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback(status);
                    }
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                });
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

Angular controller that uses service

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app')
           .controller('controller', controller);

    function controller($scope, service) {

        $scope.save = function () {
            var person = {
                Id: $scope.item.id,
                Name: $scope.item.name
            };

            service.update(personId, person, function (status) {
                $scope.msg = 'Data saved';
            });
        };
    }
})();
```

In case you are using .NET infrastructure, your service can look like.

```
namespace App.Controllers.Api
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TodoController : Controller
    {
        [FromServices]
        public ITodoRepository Repository { get; set; }

        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Update(int id, [FromBodyModels.TodoModel data)
        {
            if (data == null || data.Id != id)
            {
                return this.HttpBadRequest();
            }

            this.Repository.Update(data);

            return new NoContentResult();
        }
    }
}
```

*For update methods you need to use PUT method instead of POST

For more information about ASP.NET 5 (next version of ASP.NET) you can refer to http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html